# How to make matcha tea without matcha whisk?

Tags: tea

How do I make a nice cup of matcha tea without the whisk?

I hear the recipe including the use of a whisk is a traditional way of making ceremonial matcha drink, but I'd like to know how to make a drink from matcha without a whisk.

Here's a photo of the tea whisk along with a bamboo spoon:
[image]

I can't get a whisk right now, but if it turns out it's really worth making matcha drink according to the ceremonial recipe, I'll be sure to get it.

---

See also: [What to use for a matcha whisk?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34417/what-to-use-for-a-matcha-whisk)

Comment: See: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34417/what-to-use-for-a-matcha-whisk

Comment: Yeah, ok. I decided to change the question, since I'm really more interested in ways of making matcha drink without a whisk, and there are lots of tutorials for the traditional recipe.

Answer (score 5):

I have had a lot of success getting matcha whipped into a nice froth (and getting rid of the little tea lumps) using a small blender, like a Magic Bullet. I just put the warm water and matcha powder into the blender, pulse it a few times, then blend it continuously for about 20 seconds.

If you don't mind putting in more elbow grease, a balloon whisk can work just as well for doing it by hand.

Answer (score 5):

I propose **shaking**.

I've been drinking matcha for a few months and I've never owned a matcha set.
Usually, I will take a [swing-top glass bottle](https://www.baderbrewing.com/sites/default/files/500ml%20clear%20flip%20top%20bottle%20homebrew_0.jpg), add some matcha powder and hot water, and shake vigorously. Then I open the bottle and pour the matcha into a cup.

Using this method, the matcha dissolves perfectly; there are no clumps in the tea nor does any of the powder stick to the bottle.
The only downside I have found so far is that some of the froth will remain inside the bottle, but most of it will still make it to the cup.
The taste does not seem different from a matcha made using a whisk, which I had a few times at a friend's place.

I imagine a cocktail shaker, or any similar closable and heat-resistant container, would also work.

Answer (score 4):

The aerolatte handheld battery-operated milk frothers work very, very well with a little practice. Seriously great crema after you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

[Coastal Tea Company](http://www.coastalteaco.com/) has a product called a "Modern Matcha Whisk" that works great for forthing up matcha. I was frustrated with using (and cleaning) traditional matcha whisks/chasens so I use this now.

You can get it on Amazon, more details are at http://www.coastalteaco.com

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. battery milk frother
2. mason jar
3. blender
4. metal kitchen whisk
5. fork

This post has full explanation and photos. Cheers! 
http://www.westendmatcha.com/blogs/news/64569285-5-easy-ways-to-make-matcha-without-a-whisk

Comment: Hey, while your link has really great answers, it would be much preferred if you summarized the answers here. If for whatever reason, the link changes, your answer would be come quite useless. It also reads much better if people don't have to click around.